# datatables - make the th header cells wrap the words

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables and am wondering if there is an option to make the header wrap.

i use compact display

[image]

the problem is, some javascript sets the width of the table header cells to a fix number of pixels.

so i want:

```
fees
covered

name
shown


amount
shown
```

in the headers

**EDIT**: the problem with adding a `<br/>` tag is that the width of the columns stay exactly the same, but i want them to become smaller, less width, see here:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use line break `<br>` in the table header:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>fees<br>covered</th>
            <th>name<br>shown</th>
            <th>amount<br>shown</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pb7s8j9/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I added an edit to my question. The main goal is that the columns are less wide. The width stays exactly the same when adding a br though, namely in this case 81px. Do you know a way to make em smaller?

Comment: @Toskan, use [`columns.width`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) for each column. See also [`autoWidth`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your table is initialised then you could use an adaption of the `title` key within a `columns` definition:

```
"title": "Your Title".split(" ").join("<br/>"), // Your<br/>Title
```

[Example JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xb9o7b7u/2/).

Comment: Which is basically the same as the answer by @Gyrocode.com